# AutoHotKey and Windows 8: Alt+Tab command does not work

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, autohotkey

I can't get it to work whether I use

> AltTab

or

> Send {Alt down}{tab}{Alt up}

I can verify that other commands work because I can get my hotkeys to display a MessageBox. It seems like W8 has changed enough things to break AHK's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> hooks.

Looking for a workaround. I am trying to map <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (and the Shift versions of them).

Answer (score 7):

Setting UIAccess=true in the executable's embedded manifest appears to solve this problem. The executable must also be in a trusted location, such as the Program Files folder. For more information and a script which makes the necessary modification for you, find [EnableUIAccess](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/70449-enable-interaction-with-administrative-programs/) on the AutoHotkey forum.

Thanks to Cliff Smolinsky for posting the following on the [Synergy issue tracker](http://synergy-foss.org/spit/issues/details/3338/):

> A number of security changes have been implemented in Windows 8 which prevent programs which are not Metro apps from injecting keys that would remove you from the Metro environment. The way this works is that the keyboard shortcut is ignored if it doesn't come from a physical keyboard or a program that has the appropriate permissions. [...] In order to have the proper permissions, the program must be built with UIAccess

I was unable to confirm this via any official source, aside from the following vague comment at MSDN:

> An accessibility application can use SendInput to inject keystrokes corresponding to application launch shortcut keys that are handled by the shell. This functionality is not guaranteed to work for other types of applications.

Comment: This answer seems credible. But I no longer have Windows 8 to test with, so I cannot in good conscience accept the answer. Please comment if you have had success!

Answer (score 5):

I found I could send an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> with the following :

> F1::SendInput, !{Tab}

In other words, I had to change "Send" to "SendInput" to get this to work with Windows 8.

Comment: I just tried. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AutoHotkey (Basic), the code base hasn't been updated since September 2009. Obviously, any fundamental changes in Windows 8 have not been addressed. [AutoHotkey_L](http://l.autohotkey.net/) is much more up-to-date, having last been updated this month. However, looking at the [changelog](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/AHKL_ChangeLog.htm), further Windows 8 support is minimal.

If your script still doesn't work even after installing AutoHotkey_L, you could try the other [Send](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/Send.htm) commands:

- SendRaw
- SendInput
- SendPlay
- SendEvent

Otherwise, you just have to be patient and wait for the developers to work on adding support for Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer gave me a lead to follow, and what worked for me (with Vista) was :

```
²::SendEvent, !{Tab}
```

Thanks!